# alert box in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

how can i use an alert box in asp.net web application without using javascript with Yes/NO option, much like messagebox in desktop (windows) application.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why you can't use javascript for the alert box?

Comment: I would question why you want an in-browser application to invoke out-of-browser type _system_ windows - you essentially prevent all tabs being browsed which is just selfish and user-unfriendly.

Comment: @cybernate: 'cause, i need to check a conditions from code, and if that is true, i need an alert with Yes/No option that could possibly catch the Yes/No event also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you can't.  That message box object is only for WinForms Development.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create one - although you could make it look like one by using an overlay div and "message box" div. The additional content would need to be controlled on the server so it would require a `POST` request to the server when displaying and another for submitting the Yes/No click.

Answer (score 0):

Write an ActiveX control?

(Please don't do that.)